# Flutter share_plus - File does not get shared on android

Tags: android, flutter, share-plus

I am unable to reproduce the issue either on a newly setup project. Unfortunately, I cannot share the project code with you.

The issue I am facing is as follows:

I have a file at `/storage/emulated/0/Download/txn-159231.pdf`.  I am calling the

```
Share.shareFiles(['/storage/emulated/0/Download/txn-159231.pdf'])
```

I have started debugging the app. And, in deed the path sent is seen correctly. Everything is working fine on flutter side. However,

```
channel.invokeMethod('shareFiles', params)
```

after it returns gives the below error.

```
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/share( 9447): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.someapp/cache/share/txn-159231.pdf
```

Answer (score 0):

since you can't share your project code, could you at least share the important bits? Also, never use direct paths. Always use the package pathprovider and a temporary directory. Hope that helps.
path_provider: ^2.0.9

Comment: How can I get the access to downloads folder using path_provider? I am using  path_provider. I was saving the file in `getExternalStorageDirectory()`. However, the path gets changed in the same way as mentioned above.